# Joining two tables without having a common ID dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge two tables in the following way

Table 1:

```
ID ||  email
j1 || john@abc.com
d2 || deanne@abc.com
```

Table 2

```
Couponcode || expirationdate || is_used
qwads123   || 12/02/2017     || yes
qwads567   || 12/02/2017     || no
```

How do I join the two tables into something like

```
ID || email || couponcode || expirationdate || is_used
```

Comment: Add one more row with sample data to one of the tables (not both.) Also specify the expected result.

Comment: this violates basic relational database rules. Simply you cant do something like this and expect identical output since the row order is not a concern in relational DB. Go with keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you want four rows, then use `cross join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

This produces all combinations between the two tables.

If you want the two "side-by-side", then add a row number and use that for the join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as rn
      from table1 t1 cross join
           (select @rn1 := 0) params
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as rn
      from table2 t2 cross join
           (select @rn2 := 0) params
     ) t2
     on t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a join without any condition. But be aware that the result might be completly useless.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2
```

This will **combine every row from table1 with every row from table2**. I doubt this is your desired result, but without any combination-condition this is everything you can get.